# Passing an argument to Redis Lua script

Tags: lua, redis, arguments

I am trying to pass an argument to my Redis Lua script using the following syntax:

redis-cli -h 127.0.0.1 -p 6379 -a my-super-secret-auth-key --eval /tmp/test.lua 0 60

However in my script when I do:
print (ARGV[1]);

I get (nil) returned. What am I doing wrong? How can I properly pass an argument to my script?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to use comma (`,`) to separate `KEYS` and `ARGV` parameters even when you don't pass any KEYS (assuming you want `0` and `60` to be passed as `ARGV`):

```
redis-cli -h 127.0.0.1 -p 6379 -a my-super-secret-auth-key --eval /tmp/test.lua , 0 60
```

In your case these parameters are taken as KEYS, not as ARGV parameters. See [Running Lua scripts](https://redis.io/topics/rediscli#running-lua-scripts) in the Redis docs.

Comment: That did it. I swear I tried that before but I must have been doing something slightly different. Thank you!